# Switching from LocalJobRunner in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop2, resourcemanager

I am running MapReduce programs using Hadoop 2.6.0. The execution seems to go well with the desired output each time round. But when i look up the resource manager web UI at localhost:8088, it is completely empty and not being updated. After looking up several resources on the net, I figured that my job is running locally. It would be great if i could find some help on how to make the switch from local execution to being handled by the hadoop cluster.

PS : Although I have come across similar posts, nothing seems to do the trick for me. I have also ensured that the xml config files are configured to reflect the use of yarn including setting mapreduce.framework.name to yarn in mapred-site.xml but to no avail yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? StackOverflow is not a coding, tutoring service...

Comment: Does your conf files are properly added ?

Comment: Never mind, I got it up and running.